# Spark SQL select a sub query into a struct

Tags: apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have an UDF accept a `Row` which is the row of sub query. My SQL shows below

```sql
SELECT
  main.id as id,
  my_udf(other) as other_content
FROM
  main_tabel AS main
LEFT JOIN other_table AS other ON main.id = other.id
```

However, `other` is not a valid field in this SQL, and the SQL dose not work. My question is how can I get a `Row` of the `other` with all fields in `other_table`?

Comment: Try passing a struct that you construct from `other_table` fields: `my_udf(struct(other.field1, other.field2, ..., other.fieldN))`

Comment: @blackbishop there may be too many columns in other_table